# implicit instantiation of undefined template error

Tags: c++

I'm using Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition) for study and having some problem.
Trying out the code written below gives me a implicit instantiation of undefined template error.
I tried addding `#include<vector>` but adding the code gives me a new compile error of no matching function for call to sort().

With my poor knowledge, I can't find the way to solve this problem so it will be really thankful to give me an advice solving it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open(){char ch; cin>> ch;}
int main(){
    vector<string>words;
    for(string temp; cin >>temp;)
    words.push_back(temp);
    cout << "Number of words:" << words.size() <<'\n';
    sort(words);
    for(int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
    if(i == 0 || words[i-1]! =words[i])
    cout << words[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you created a function called sort anywhere

Comment: If you're hoping to use `std::sort` then you're using it incorrectly. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort You do need to include vector, string, and algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tried adding `#include<algorithm>` `#include<vector>`   
`#include<functional>` `#include <array>` 
`#include <string_view>` but nothing seems to success.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. after fixing the sort method, everthing went fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two core problems. The first one is you're missing *several* headers:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
```

`string` is for, well, `std::string`, and similarly, `vector` for `std::vector`. `algorithm` is for `std::sort`.

The second one is that's not the how `std::sort` should be called, since it needs a pair of iterators:

```
sort(words.begin(), words.end());
```